# Simple harmonic motion centered at the origin

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, waves, harmonic-oscillator, coordinate-systems, conventions

I'm doing a problem on the simple harmonic motion but I didn't understand it really well.

> The problem says: "**A point describes a simple harmonic motion centered at the origin, the period is T=0.628s. *For t = 0 point's position is x=0.15m*** etc..."

What it means with "harmonic motion is centered at the origin"? I thought that *x=0 when t=0* but this is not right apparently.

Comment: -1. Of course it is not right! The question states that $t=0$ when $x=0.15$. It cannot also be at $x=0$ when $t=0$. It cannot be at two places at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is symmetric about $x=0$.  Thus, starting from 
$$
x(t)= x_0\cos(\omega t+ \phi)
$$
you can derive $\omega$ and the phase $\phi$ from the data of your problem.

A solution *not* symmetric about the origin would be of the form 
$$
x(t)= A+ x_0\cos(\omega t+ \phi)\, .
$$
The harmonic motion would then be "centered" about $A$.

Comment: Oh I understand now! It was strange because the book didn't tackle no asymmetric SHM yet. Thank you a lot :)

Comment: @Peto this kind of language occurs because one *could* choose to have $x=0$ at the point where the sho is attached to a wall (if a spring-mass system).  Then the equilibrium position would be at some position $\ne 0$.

Comment: Yes it seems pretty legit. What I had understood is that the origin was the center of the axes ...but they're not the same in this kind of problems!

Answer (score 1):

It means that the SHM, in other words the body's oscillations such that its $a \propto x$, are oscillations that are about the origin. It does not necessarily imply that at $t = 0$, $x = 0$. For example, think of a pendulum which starts with from either the left or the right side to the bob's mean position. At $ t = 0$, it is starting from a position, $x \neq 0$.